# How to compare words in a string/python dictionary?

Tags: python, string, dictionary

I have a dictionary item in the form

```
 {"value for money": ["rescheduled", "cost", "low", "high", "simplicity", "booking", "price-performance", "satisfied", "satisfaction", "pricing", "prices"]}
```

I need to check whether the a  string like "I love simplicity" contains any word from this dictionary.

Can't figure how to define the code for this.

Comment: Basic `for` loop can solve this, could you elaborate the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
mydict =  {"value for money": ["rescheduled", "cost", "low", "high", "simplicity", "booking", "price-performance", "satisfied", "satisfaction", "pricing", "prices"]}
mystring = "I love simplicity"
if any((word in mystring) for word in mydict["value for money"]):
    print("Found one.")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
d={"value for money": ["rescheduled", "cost", "low", "high", "simplicity", "booking", "price-performance", "satisfied", "satisfaction", "pricing", "prices"]}
s="I love simplicity" 

for w in s.split(' '):
  if w in d["value for money"]:
    print (w," is in value for money")
```

Answer (score 1):

If your dictionary contains "value for money" key only or you need only the values of that key and you need to know only if any word from the input string is in those values:

```
def is_in_dict(string, dictionary):
    for word in string.split():
        if word in dictionary['value for money']:
            return True
    return False
```

If your dict has many other keys and you need to check them all:

```
def is_in_dict(string, dictionary):
    for word in string.split():
        for values in dictionary.values():
            if word in values:
                return True
    return False
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use loops:

```
string = 'I love simplicity'
dictionary =  {"value for money": ["rescheduled", "cost", "low", "high", "simplicity", "booking", "price-performance", "satisfied", "satisfaction", "pricing", "prices"]}

for word in dictionary['value for money']:
    if word in string:
        print(word)
```

If you want to use generators:

`[word for word in dictionary['value for money'] if word in string]`